# Leer archivo de texto y guardarlo en un array en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un archivo tipo `txt` con lo siguiente

```
20022, Juan Perez, 28, 0299222, 2
20223, Rigo Canales, 29, 09888, 2
20022, Ramon Chavez, 34, 09222, 4
```

Necesito leer el archivo de texto después guardar esa data en un arreglo para luego insertar en una tabla hasta el momento tengo algo como:

Leo el archivo con un `StreamReader` pero me falta el guardado en un array

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que ya has abierto el archivo con `System.Io.File` tienes que usar el método de StreamReader `ReadLine()` para ir lellendo tu archivo de texto linea a linea.

Ten en cuenta para entender el código que cuando `ReadLine()` intenta leer una línea y no quedan mas lineas dentro del archivo debuelve `null`. El código sería algo así:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string contenidoArchivo = ""; //variable donde se van a guardar todas las lineas.

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("C:\Direccion\De\Tu\Archivo.txt")) //abrimos el archivo de texto
        {
            string s; //variable que va a almacenar cada línea
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) //lee una linea y si la linea existe ejecuta lo que hay dentro del while sino se acaba la lectura
            {
                contenidoArchivo = contenidoArchivo + "\n" + s;// añado la linea a la variable que almacena el contenido del archivo.


            }
        }
    }
}
```